# TextView disappears if other textView is too long

Tags: android, layout, textview, alignment

I have a problem...
I have 2 textViews, and they should appear one after another. The problem occurs if the first textView is too long because it makes the other view disappear:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:text="Here is the loooooong text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_tv"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Second text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I can not align one textView to left, and the other to right because they should appear one after another (if the first textView contains, for example, just two words, second textView should be just 8dp right of the first view).
How can I make so that if the first textView is long, if it reaches the end of layout width breaks to new line without to make the second view disappear?

Comment: you can use android:maxLength="40", for your textview that will not exceeds char size of 40 to override disappear of textview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:text="Here is the loooooong text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Second text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

[image]

**Code Here :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="With Relative or Linear layouts when first TextView contains big text - second text simply disappeared from screen."
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="TextView"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Here is the loooooooooooooong text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_odd_type_played"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="some text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView  
                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
            </TextView>

            <TextView  
                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
            </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```